# Error with C++ operator overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class complex {
    double real;
    double image;
public:
    complex(double r=0,double i=0) : real(r), image(i) { };
    complex(const complex& c) : real(c.real), image(c.image) { };
    ~complex(){};
    double re() const {
        return real;
    };
    double im() const{
        return image;
    };
    const complex& operator =(const complex&c)
    {
        real = c.real;
        image = c.image;
        return *this;
    };
    const complex& operator +=(const complex&c)
    {
        real += c.real;
        image += c.image;
        return *this;
    };
    const complex& operator -=(const complex&c)
    {
        real -= c.real;
        image -= c.image;
        return *this;
    };
    const complex& operator *=(const complex&c)
    {
        double keepreal=real;
        real = real * c.real - image * c.image;
        image = keepreal * c.image + image * c.real;
        return *this;
    };
    const complex& operator /=(double d)
    {
        real/=d;
        image/=d;
        return *this;
    };

    friend complex operator !(const complex &c)
    {
        return complex(c.re(),-c.im());
    };
    friend double abs2(const complex& c)
    {
        return (c.re() * c.re() + c.im() * c.im());
    };
    const complex& operator /=(const complex&c)
    {   
        return *this *= (!c) /= abs2(c);
    };
    const complex operator +(const complex& c, const complex& d)
    {
        return complex(c.re() + d.re(), c.im() + d.im());
    };
    const complex operator -(const complex& c, const complex& d)
    {
        return complex(c.re() - d.re(), c.im() - d.im());
    };
    const complex operator -(const complex&c)
    {
        return complex(-c.re(), -c.im());
    };
    const complex operator /(const complex& c,const complex& d)
    {
        return complex(c) /= d;
    };
};

int main() {
    complex c = 1., d(3.,4.);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

> Line 62: error: 'const complex
>       complex::operator+(const complex&,
>       const complex&)' must take either
>       zero or one argument
>   compilation
>       terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

please help: http://codepad.org/cOOMmqw1

Comment: The answers in the error... your operator+ should only have one argument, it should look like you're operator- function, only obviously the math is the other way...  const complex operator+(const complex&c).  You are going to have the same problem with your operator- that takes two arguments and your operator/

Comment: You shouldn't make `operator+()` a member. You'll find an introduction to operator overloading in C++ at [this FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two alternatives to overload the binary + operator, as a free function or as a member function. As a member function the signature is `Type operator+( Type const & ) const` (`const` is optional there, but I am assuming that `a+b` does not modify `a`, which seems a fair assumption).

The alternative approach is using a free function that takes two objects and returns the sum. There are different signatures for this, but the most widely accepted would be: `Type operator+( Type lhs, Type const & rhs )` (note that the first argument is *by value*), where the implementation internally modifies and returns `lhs`. In particular a common approach to arithmetic operator overloading is implementing `operator+=` as a member function, and then implementing a free function `operator+` in terms of the former:

```
struct Type {
   // ...
   Type& operator+=( Type const & );
};
Type operator+( Type lhs, Type const & rhs ) {
   return lhs+=rhs;
}
```

This way, you don't need to grant friendship to the free function. In some cases, in particular with templates, it is sometimes recommended to define the operator inside the class definition, and in that case you will have to make it a `friend` (not for access, but for syntactic reasons:

```
struct Type {
   // ...
   Type& operator+=( Type const & );
   // Still a free function:
   friend Type operator+( Type lhs, Type const & rhs ) {
      return lhs+=rhs;
   }
};
```

As of the reasons to use this pattern... Implementing `operator+=` first and then `operator+` on top of it provides the two separate operations for little extra cost (`operator+` is a one-liner function!). Implementing it as a member function (`operator+=` could also be a free function) makes it similar to `operator=` (must be member) and avoids the need for friendship.

The reason for implementing `operator+` as a free function are related to type symmetry of the operation. Addition is commutative (`a+b` == `b+a`), and you would expect the same while using your type. You have provided an implicit constructor (your complex type can be implicitly converted from an int due to the constructor `complex( double r = 0, double i = 0 )`, and that allows the compiler to use those conversions if a function call does not perfectly match an overload.

If `operator+` is implemented as a member function, the compiler is only allowed to consider that overload when the first argument is a `complex`, and will implicitly convert the other argument, allowing you to type `complex(0,0)+5`. The problem is that if you reverse the order `5+complex(0,0)` the compiler cannot convert `5`to a complex and then use the member `operator+`. On the other hand, if you provide it as a free function, the compiler will detect that one of the two arguments matches in both cases, and will try and succeeds converting the other argument. The net result is that by using a free function you are allowing with a single implementation all these three additions: `complex+complex`, `complex+double`, `double+complex` (and additionally for all integral and floating point types, since they can be converted to `double`

Having `operator+` take the first argument by value means that the compiler can under some circumstances elide a copy: `a + b + c` binds as `(a+b) + c`, the temporary result of the first operation can be used directly as argument to the second call, without extra copying.

Answer (score 5):

You overload the +,/,-, and * like this

```
complex operator+(const complex& c) const
```

You only need one argument since the left hand argument is `this`

Example

```
complex operator+(const complex& c) const 
{
    return complex(c.re()+this->re(),c.im()+this->im());
};
```

Comment: The signature for a member function should probably be `complex operator+( const complex& ) const` (the `const` in the return could be optional but does not really add much, and it is not common, the `const` in the function assumes the basic understanding that `a+b` returns an object without modifying `a` or `b`, just in the same way that you have used a constant reference for the argument). And at any rate it is usually recommended to implement `operator+` as a free function.

Comment: @David Thanks for the input, I agree I'll modify the answer

Answer (score 2):

The + operator should take one parameter:

```
complex operator+(const complex& c) const
{ 
   return complex(c.re()+re(),c.im()+im());
}
```

The other complex is the current object.

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
const complex operator+(const complex& c, const complex& d)
{
return complex(c.re()+d.re(),c.im()+d.im());
};
```

is a member function of `complex`. That prototype is for a global `operator+`. In a member function `c` is assumed to be `*this`, so is not specified.

But you really need to start formatting your code properly, starting with indenting. Beginning programmers don't realize how important proper formatting is when showing your code to others.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way to overload binary operator, if you are really looking for two parameters operator overloading. Then you can try something like this.

```
friend complex operator+(const complex& c, const complex& d)
 {
  complex r;
  r.real = c.re() + d.re();
  r.image = c.im() + d.im();
  return r;
 }
```

Comment: 1) don't think you can declare a functiona as a `friend` of `complex`, it's up to the `complex` class to declare who his friends are; 2) you actually don't need `friend` at all - assuming `complex` has an obvious constructor, rewrite the free `operator+` like this: `{ return complex(c.re()+d.re(), c.im()+d.im();}

Comment: @davka: That syntax is to be used *inside* the `complex` type definition, it is both a declaration of friendship and the definition of the befriended function.

Comment: @David - oh, I see. but the (2) still stands