# Overloading + operator, Linked Lists

Tags: c++, overloading, addition, operator-keyword

In my text book they give an example of overloading the + operator

```
Sales_item operator+ (const Sales_item& lhs, const Sales_item& rhs)
 {
   Sales_item ret(lhs);
   ret += rhs;
   return ret;
 }
```

But when I try it for my linked list, it tells me it can only take zero or one argument.

What is it that I'm not seeing and how would you even add 2 objects if you can't take 2 arguments?

Comment: Move it outside of your class.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069286/1670308), it might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

If your operartor+ is a member function it doesn't need two arguments, as the object of the class you call operator+ on is the left-hand side argument. But you have already such an operator: operator+=. As it was suggested by chris and nims move operator+ outside Sales_item class.